# development for DEP/VPP apis from an unsupported country

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-vpp

I am trying to add DEP and VPP support in my MDM solution but my country does not yet support these programs, is there any way to get around this limitation for development purposes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to have access to a company account within a country where the programs are supported, and get access to the tokens (and a device, in case of DEP, although with iOS 11 you could add any device to an active DEP program AFAIC, using Apple Configurator).

This is why all MDM vendors usually have someone in the US :)